# Dequeue in a priority queue

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, priority-queue

I have implemented a priority queue with array (school work), and it looks like below:

```
int dequeue(int a[], int n){

    int i, numberToDequeue;
    numberToDequeue = a[0];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a[i] = a[i+1];
    }
    return numberToDequeue;
}
```

Dequeue in a priority queue should take O(1) time.

However, in my code, it takes O(1) time to dequeue and

O(n) time to shift all the elements to front by 1 index.

I was wondering if there's any better solution that has the time complexity of O(1).

All form of reply will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Queues don't really need to be placed into contiguous memory...

Comment: Lookup C++ circular buffer

Comment: Well I figured out that I can actually sort my numbers in ascending order, so I can just decrease my arraySize after each dequeue instead of having a for loop to shift every element to the front by 1 index.

Answer (score 0):

```
int dequeue(int a[], int n){ //provided that the numbers are in ascending order

    int numberToDequeue;
    numberToDequeue = a[n - 1];
    n--;
    return numberToDequeue;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.